# import tensorlfow failed with errors "undefined symbol: omp_get_num_threads"

Tags: tensorflow, openmp, bazel

Import tensorflow failed due to message "undefined symbol: omp_get_num_threads"

 1. I configure tensorflow by "-O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -DEIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL -DMKL_ILP64 -fopenmp -m64 -v -I/opt/intel/mkl/include".

 2. Build tensorflow by "bazel build --copt=-march="haswell" --config=opt -c opt  //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package"

 3. After finishing building, run "bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg"

 4. Pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl

 5. Run command "python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.**version**)""

 6. Get the error message "ImportError: /home/admin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: omp_get_num_threads"

The whole statck is as belows:

 [Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/home/admin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in 
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/admin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 49, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/admin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/admin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/admin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /home/admin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: omp_get_num_threads]

Comment: The omp_num_threads call should be satisfied by linking with gcc -fopenmp or explicit link of -lgomp

Comment: Thanks for your comments, while i built successfully, but  runtime failed. I will try this later soon.

Comment: problem resolved , thanks, fixed by command "bazel build --config opt --copt="-fopenmp"  --copt="-lgomp""